# App for receiving SMS works fine first time it runs, second time all messages are not displayed

Tags: java, android, listview

I have some issues with my SMS-receiver. The application runs as it should the first time. All messages are displayed in my listview as long as I do not close the application.

If I do close my app, the second time it behaves strange. Usually only the first message is displayed. when the first message "arrives" to the app, the built-in sms app does not show a preview of the message. On the second message and forward, the message in the built in app are displayed. (I am both receiving and sending the messages from the same phone, same problems occur if the messages are received from an other phone though)

If more than one message is displaed, its a copy of the first one.

I have two classes;

```
package com.example.t.receivesms;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static ArrayList<String> messageList=new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    mAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messageList);
    ListView listView=findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String address = extras.getString("MessageNumber");
        String message = extras.getString("Message");
        String conCatString=("From:"+address +"\n"+ message);
        messageList.add(conCatString);

    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

and

```
package com.example.t.receivesms;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SMSManager extends BroadcastReceiver{


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage messages =SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);

    Intent smsIntent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    smsIntent.putExtra("MessageNumber", messages.getOriginatingAddress());
    smsIntent.putExtra("Message", messages.getMessageBody());
    context.startActivity(smsIntent);

    Toast.makeText(context, "You have a new message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

If its helpfull;

Logcat:

```
12-03 21:34:55.437 15863-15863/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-03 21:34:55.741 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
12-03 21:34:55.791 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms V/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [loadFeatureFromXml] *** start feature loading from xml
12-03 21:34:55.791 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [parse] Load xml
12-03 21:34:55.794 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms V/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [getMatchedProfile] selected file : /cust/OPEN_EU/config/featureset.xml
12-03 21:34:55.794 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : handle8bit, value : true
12-03 21:34:55.794 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : ConcatMTCheckTimestamp, value : true
12-03 21:34:55.794 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : allow_sending_empty_sms, value : true
12-03 21:34:55.794 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : retry_to_enable_cb, value : true
12-03 21:34:55.794 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : copy_submit_to_uicc, value : true
12-03 21:34:55.794 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : spam, value : true
12-03 21:34:55.795 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : MANUAL_SELECTION_WITH_RAT, value : true
12-03 21:34:55.795 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : SUPPORT_LOG_RF_INFO, value : true
12-03 21:34:55.795 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : seperate_processing_sms_uicc, value : true
12-03 21:34:55.795 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : KRWapPushWithSpam, value : true
12-03 21:34:55.795 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : GLOBALspam, value : true
12-03 21:34:55.795 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : support_emoji_in_concat_message, value : true
12-03 21:34:55.795 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : KSC5601Decoding, value : true
12-03 21:34:55.795 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : KR_Modem_Item, value : true
12-03 21:34:55.795 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : OperatorMessage, value : true
12-03 21:34:55.795 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms V/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [loadFeatureFromXml] load feature from xml complete : {handle8bit=true, ConcatMTCheckTimestamp=true, retry_to_enable_cb=true, allow_sending_empty_sms=true, copy_submit_to_uicc=true, spam=true, MANUAL_SELECTION_WITH_RAT=true, seperate_processing_sms_uicc=true, SUPPORT_LOG_RF_INFO=true, KRWapPushWithSpam=true, GLOBALspam=true, KSC5601Decoding=true, support_emoji_in_concat_message=true, KR_Modem_Item=true, OperatorMessage=true}
12-03 21:34:55.808 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.t.receivesms time:150316365
12-03 21:34:56.029 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/ContextHelper: convertTheme. context->name=com.example.t.receivesms themeResourceId=2131492869
12-03 21:34:56.082 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
12-03 21:34:56.133 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms I/PhoneWindow: [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
12-03 21:34:56.180 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/PhoneWindowEx: [LMJ][PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xfff5f5f5
12-03 21:34:56.180 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x fff5f5f5
12-03 21:34:56.565 15863-15889/com.example.t.receivesms D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
12-03 21:34:56.566 15863-15889/com.example.t.receivesms I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
                                                                      OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
                                                                      Build Date: 12/12/14 금
                                                                      Local Branch: LA.BF.1.1_RB1.05.00.00.002.031_20141212_01821442
                                                                      Remote Branch: 
                                                                      Local Patches: 
                                                                      Reconstruct Branch: 
12-03 21:34:56.567 15863-15889/com.example.t.receivesms I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-03 21:34:56.589 15863-15889/com.example.t.receivesms D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
12-03 21:34:56.602 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms D/Atlas: Validating map...
12-03 21:34:56.848 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
12-03 21:34:56.923 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@24e2b0b3 time:150317479
12-03 21:35:03.132 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.t.receivesms time:150323689
12-03 21:35:03.542 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@24e2b0b3 time:150324098
12-03 21:35:11.576 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.t.receivesms time:150332132
12-03 21:35:11.823 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@24e2b0b3 time:150332379
12-03 21:35:21.787 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.t.receivesms time:150342343
12-03 21:35:22.096 15863-15863/com.example.t.receivesms I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@24e2b0b3 time:150342653
```

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how to change the app?

Comment: The questions has now been edited.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code sample I can see that you are only listing the sms as they arrive via the BroadcastReceiver.

So here is what happens.

SMS received> BroadcastReceiver receives SMS then you call your activity that displays the message.

What it does is you are only listing the messages as they arrive, but not persisting your list. The list is just alive while your app is alive, so when it gets killed by the system or you force close it the next time you open it the list would be recreated. And your data is lost.

One way to solve this is to save these sms on your own storage through SQLite or SharedPreference.
If you want to actually get all the SMS you could use the ContentResolver and get the SMS within the phone.

A method that gets SMS using content resolver into a list would look something like this:

```
public ArrayList<Sms> getAllSms() {
    ArrayList<Sms> lstSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();
    Sms objSms = new Sms();
    Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    ContentResolver cr = mcontext.getContentResolver();

    Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, null, null, null);
    mcontext.startManagingCursor(c);
    totalSMS = c.getCount();

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {

            objSms = new Sms();
            objSms.displayName=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
            objSms.address=c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
            objSms.msg=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
            objSms.threadId=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("read"));
            objSms.date=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).contains("1")) {
                objSms.type="inbox";
            } else {
                objSms.type="sent";
            }

            lstSms.add(objSms);

            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    c.close();

    return lstSms;
}
```